# Is it possible to use if condition in base class to effect child class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to use an if statment in a base class and depending on the value either continue execution of the parent class method or just return.

here is a small example I made.

main class to create two parent classes

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();

        Class2 c2 = new Class2();

        c1.test();

        c2.test();

    }
}
```

This is the base class that contains the method to be ovveridden

```
public class baseClass
{

    public bool b = true;

    public virtual void test()
    {
        if(!b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("b is true returning");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Parent Class 1

```
public class Class1 : baseClass
{
    public override void test()
    {
        base.test();

        //the below line should only execute if b is true
        Console.WriteLine("Executing a method unique to Class1");
    }
}
```

Parent Class 2

```
public class Class2 : baseClass
{
    public override void test()
    {
        b = false;
        base.test();

        //the below line should only execute if b is true
        Console.WriteLine("Executing a method unique to Class2");
    }
}
```

I really simplified it there and it looks kind of pointless but I am trying to explain what I want to do with code.

Basically in my base class I will check if a list is empty and if it is I just want to return and not continue execution of the parent class method. However if it is not empty each parent class will do something different with the list.

**EDIT**
Here is a fiddle, What I am trying to achieve is it should not print out the line from Class2.test()

https://dotnetfiddle.net/p67UgJ

Comment: What you considered changing `test` to return `bool`? Then your inheriting class can check the return value of `base.test()` and use an `if` to decide what to do in response.

Comment: That seems to be working, no? What are you asking here?

Comment: You may make your `b`-flag `protected` to ensure only the child-classes can modify its value. But apart from this: what´s your question? Doesn´t do that code what you want it to do?

Comment: You also seem to do `if(!b)` then print `b is true returning`..but `b` isn't true. This is all **very** confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate the part of the method you want to override, rather than override the whole method.

```
public class baseClass
{
    public bool b = true;

    public void test()
    {
        if(!b)
        {
            BitThatNeedsToChange();
            return;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void BitThatNeedsToChange()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("b is true returning");
    }
}
```

In your derived classes you would override the `protected virtual` method:

```
public class Class1 : baseClass
{
    protected override void BitThatNeedsToChange()
    {
        //the below line should only execute if b is true
        Console.WriteLine("Executing a method unique to Class1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct. To elaborate: The `return;` at the end of a void method is redundant. Moreover, when you return from a virtual method, that does not mean you will return the same in it's override - calling `base.Test()` will not stop the execution of `Test()` in the derived classes - it's just like calling any other method.